# How can I include Google Search into the website?

Tags: web-applications

I want to include Google custom search into my website

Please check what I actually want to add - http://screencast.com/t/rMZcLLlByV

So please provide me full information for include Google search into the website.

Comment: http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_can_i_add_a_google_search_box_to_my_web_site/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your screenshot suggests you need 'google custom search' which is now possible with the 'Google Custom Search Engine' (easier to integrate).

There is a simple process to create this if you log in to the CSE site here https://www.google.com/cse/, with a valid Google account.

This will create the HTML needed to place on your page for the search to work.

Comment: when i have implement through your suggestion i got this check http://screencast.com/t/aiski0jpI. now actually i want look and feel like this -http://screencast.com/t/rMZcLLlByV so can you help me to implement in right way

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [**Google Custom Search API**](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

> The **Google Custom Search API** lets you develop websites and programs to
>   retrieve and display search results from Google Custom Search
>   programmatically. With this API, you can use RESTful requests to get
>   either web search or image search results in JSON or Atom format.

Comment: Hi 

My website is http://career.guru99.com/

now i have successfully add google custom search but look and feel of google custom search is not good as per as my requirement.

here you can check what i actually want - http://screencast.com/t/rMZcLLlByV

But in actual my google custom search look like this - http://screencast.com/t/aiski0jpI

and i want google custom search here - http://screencast.com/t/fKSCOojxYc

So please help me to do this

Comment: I am using enfold theme